# Bootstrap 5 CSS overriding vars — changing default $green value also changes btn-success text color?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm loading my Bootstrap 5 sass like this:

```
@import '_partials/bs_var_overrides';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

In `bs_var_overrides` I'm simply doing this:

```
$green: #00ff00;
```

Naturally this changes the bs var default of `$primary: $green` *which is what I want*.

However, in my `btn-success` buttons, it's also changing the text color from white to black and I'm trying to understand why(?)

Comment: Follow : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/buttons/#variables 
And `white to black` due to shade-color function like `@function shade-color($color, $percentage) {
    @return mix(black, $color, $percentage);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`white to black` due to shade-color function like:
@function shade-color($color, $percentage) {
     @return mix(black, $color, $percentage);
}

*Helpful Links*:
[getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/buttons/#variables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/buttons/#variables)
https://codepen.io/raeesh/pen/OJQmxrj 
----------------------------
**bs_var_overrides.scss** File
$green: #00ff00;
$primary: $green;

**Style.scss** File
@import '_partials/bs_var_overrides';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

/* If you want btn-success color should be **white** */
.btn-success {
--bs-btn-color: var(--bs-white);
}